# new Date() deprecated in open jdk 11? or no supported

Tags: java, date

I'm having an issue with Date library current week. When you google it's week 11, but my function returns 12. In terms of location, I am in South Africa, but the same issue is reported by someone in Germany who is testing the application. I wrote below code to test this in a small piece of code and I see when I get calendar using new Date() library, it's returning 12, but when I use Localdate.now() it's returning 11.

I updated the Dockerfile jdk initially it was **jdk8** and now it's **openjdk11**. Can this be the reason I am getting different results? Is `new Date()` no longer supported in Java 11?

Below is the code snippet. I would love if some can assist me on this.

```java
package com.company;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class CalenderLibrary {
    private static Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        String calendarWeekFromEvent = getCalendarWeekFromEventWithDate(date);
        System.out.println("Date: {} " + calendarWeekFromEvent);

        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        String localDate1 = getCalendarWeekFromEventWithLocalDate(localDate);
        System.out.println("LocalDate: {} " + localDate1);


    }

    private static String getCalendarWeekFromEventWithLocalDate(LocalDate date) {
        return String.valueOf(date.get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR));
    }

    private static String getCalendarWeekFromEventWithDate(Date date) {
        cal.setTime(date);
        return String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Date: {} 12

LocalDate: {} 11
```

Comment: You're using different fields: `ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR` is not the same as `WEEK_OF_YEAR`. This is clearly indicated by their docs: first is aligned to start of the year, second is not.

Comment: Be aware that week numbering is different from country to country. Today, it is week 11 in Germany, but week 12 in South Africa.

Comment: Not officially deprecated, but I recommend you avoid using `Date` and `Calendar`. Also mixing outdated and modern classes brings nothing but needless complication. Stick to the modern java.time classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` are not deprecated, and still work as they always have. However, how they work is difficult to use, which is why `java.time` classes are recommended instead.

What you are seeing is the difference between `WEEK_OF_YEAR` (which depends on the locale) and `ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR` (which is the same in all locales).

> When setting or getting the `WEEK_OF_MONTH` or `WEEK_OF_YEAR` fields, `Calendar` must determine the first week of the month or year as a reference point. The first week of a month or year is defined as the earliest seven day period beginning on `getFirstDayOfWeek()` and containing at least `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` days of that month or year. Weeks numbered ..., -1, 0 precede the first week; weeks numbered 2, 3,... follow it. Note that the normalized numbering returned by `get()` may be different. For example, a specific Calendar subclass may designate the week before week 1 of a year as week n of the previous year.

---

> `ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR` represents concept of the count of weeks within the period of a year where the weeks are aligned to the start of the year. This field is typically used with `ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_YEAR`.
>
> For example, in a calendar systems with a seven day week, the first aligned-week-of-year starts on day-of-year 1, the second aligned-week starts on day-of-year 8, and so on. Thus, day-of-year values 1 to 7 are in aligned-week 1, while day-of-year values 8 to 14 are in aligned-week 2, and so on.

---

And for the locale difference:

```java
// returns DayOfWeek.MONDAY
WeekFields.of(Locale.forLanguageTag("de-DE")).getFirstDayOfWeek();

// returns DayOfWeek.SUNDAY
WeekFields.of(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-ZA")).getFirstDayOfWeek();
```

To get the unaligned week of year using the current system local with `java.time`:

```java
LocalDate.now().get(WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).weekOfYear())
```

If you want to be locale-independent, then there is `ISO.weekOfYear()` if you want the week to start on a Monday, and `SUNDAY_START.weekOfYear()` for a Sunday.

Comment: And regarding the last statement ('if you want to be locale-independent ...'), there are also other differences between ISO and SUNDAY_START, not just that Monday or Sunday are counted as the first day of the week. The ISO rule is defined to have January 4th in week number 1 while the SUNDAY_START rule is defined to have January 1st in week number 1.

Answer (score 0):

The old, much-derided Date and Calendar classes have always been confusing and difficult to use properly, particularly in a multi-threaded context.Java 8’s JSR 310 implementation offers specific classes for:

[image]

The old date library included only a single time representation class – java.util.Date, which despite its name, is actually a timestamp. It only stores the number of milliseconds elapsed since the Unix epoch.

Comment: Joda did indeed try to solve problems with the old Date API, but introduced a lot of new problems and inconsistencies. For example relevant for this problem: Joda did not have support for localized week numbers at all. OPs problem could not have been solved with Joda at all. Even if they had their limitations and were not always easy to use, the old Date API hat at least a broad set of functionality and worked as documented.

Comment: Yes. we should use Java 8 date and TIme APi instead. like:  LocalDate, LocalTime and LocalDateTime

Comment: Why is this written like "now" wasn't eight years ago?

Comment: @MaximBezmen So why are you mentioning Joda? Joda has been obsolete for almost 10 years since the introduction of Java 8 and as I already pointed out was even before that not suitable for solving OP's problem. And even ignoring that, your answer does not do anything to explain the difference between the old and new Java APIs OP is asking about. In this case, it was actually even the old API doing correctly what OP was trying to achieve.

Comment: The screenshot appears to be a listing of the ThreeTen library, not what was actually in Java 8.

Comment: @ jarnbjo
Yes you are right. The main idea was to talk about New Java 8 Date Time API (https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)